# Angular http.get request is not working as intended

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to build front end for a request from my web api. The model for the response is:

```
export class User {
    ID: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

In the user.components, I use following code:

```
 users: User[];

 ngOnInit(){        
        this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.users = data;
            });
    }
```

For the service:

```
   getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
        return this.http.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl+"/users");
```

For the html:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.isAdmin}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Console answer: [Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acSMj.png)

I don't get any error and I can see the result in the console. However, I can not see the answer on the web page. I have tried several things and found out that I can see the answer if I use same variable name in the "User" class as in the backend. Is this how it should be or am I making a mistake in somewhere?

Comment: What's the content of user.components.html?

Comment: You should share both html and console data in question to understand problem

Comment: Yes if your names are not the same on client and server, it will use the server once. As it is what you get back. It will not do any magic or automapping. You should use same names or map them correctly

Comment: I edited question with console data and html. @SehaxX I still get the answer if I remove model in angular part. What is the point of using model in the angular then?

Comment: You have only mismatching user_ID . I wonder if you have any user variable in your component.ts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only trying to conform the received data to a particular object structure, then Typescript [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) is rather a better fit than a class. Interfaces are only available at compile time and can be used to check if the received data is of the actual type expected.

```js
export interface User {
  user_ID: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

But the most important thing is, we are trying to assert that the object structure from the backend is of a specific type. But from you screenshot, the ID is called `user_ID`, so you should either change it in the front end to `user_ID` or change it in the backend to `ID`. The object properties from the backend should exactly match the object properties in the frontend. You are allowed to declared optional properties though.

```js
export interface User {
  user_ID: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name?: string;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
}
```

Here `last_name` and `isAdmin` properties are optional. So the following two assignments are valid

```js
obj1: User = { user_ID: 1, first_name: 'sample' };
obj2: User = { user_ID: 1, first_name: 'sample', last_name: 'sample' };
```

Classes are usually helpful when you need to modify the data and perform some calculations. They need to instantiated akin to other OOP based classes.

Lastly, TS interfaces and classes exist for type assertions (type checkings) and to append more traditional OOP based methodologies to Javascript. So in theory no specific type is required to use data from the backend. For what it's worth, you could simply do

Services

```js
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+"/users");
}
```

Component

```
users: any;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am aware of the ID and user_ID duality. I have a follow up question. In the frontend side, I can show the answer in webpage even if I don't use any model or interface for the response as long as I use the same naming convention in the html and backend side. Then what is point of using a interface in the backend side?

Comment: @cemklkn: I can't actually comment on the backend without seeing it's implementation.

Comment: I am asking the question in the conceptual level. What is the "best practice" way of doing it?

Comment: That would be to define definite types that are identical in the front-end and the back-end. Interfaces would be for guiding the type signature and classes would be for runtime classes with it's own properties and methods. That is one of the reason for usage of *Type*script.